# Automating interaction with a closed-sourced Windows XP GUI-based Program

Tags: java, python, windows, interaction

I've a closed-sourced Windows XP GUI-based that performs some measurements.

My current manual workflow is:

1. Start the data capture by clicking on the "Run" button on the GUI
2. Stop the data capture by pressing the "Stop" button on the GUI.
3. Read some value displayed on the screen.
4. Save the data for the session to a file.

There is no library or API to automate this whole interaction and therefore I've no option but to do it manually :( and I'm sick of it !

As you clearly see that this approach is not only time-consuming but also error prone because it is limited by my reaction time which varies with every run.

I was wondering if there is a way to automate this interaction? If yes, what are my options? I would prefer to implement something in Python or Java. But I'm open to other options as well.

My idea is to implement a server process that runs on the Windows XP machine. I can then remotely send requests to this server process which in turn will execute my workflow automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an amazing windows GUI automation tool called autoit. http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: I strongly second this advice. Autoit was built just for this purpose, and Java wasn't. If you tried to use Java for this, you'd have to either use JNI or JNA to make OS calls (or link Java with AutoIt, something I've done when necessary). 1+ to this answer.

Comment: I see this answer is quite old, there has been any recent better options?

Answer (score 0):

You asked about linking AutoIt with Java. For my purposes, I've done this using a ProcessBuilder to create a Process, then get the Processes InputStream and ErrorStream and be sure to handle these streams in a separate thread. I have AutoIt communicate with my Java program using the InputStream. A good article for this (though a little out of date) is this one: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). It is key to be sure that the process be run on a background thread and that the two streams be read in their own threads. If you're doing this in a Swing GUI, then extra care must be taken that all Swing calls be made on the main Swing event thread, the EDT.